# Including links in Phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to get clickable links in my pdf using Phantomjs. The links that I have specified in my html page using anchor tags do not render into clickable links in the pdf. I am using version 1.9.0. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><span><a href="https://www.google.com">Here</a></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's a trial html where I've included the link to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade your PhantomJS version if you can. Usually newer versions have fewer bugs, more capabilities and better performance.

Current PhantomjS version is 2.1.1 and using that version I made a PDF of your HTML with the perfectly clickable link.

The sample script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';

page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 1024 };

page.open('https://jsbin.com/buxuxanigo/edit?output', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('jsbin.pdf');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
});
```

The result PDF is tested in Foxit PDF Reader under Windows 7:

[image: Demo of clickling link in PDF]

Comment: Yeah ! I found out that this was a bug which was solved in version 2.1.1 
Tried it with that and it worked like a charm. Thanks anyways.